# How to add border to PrintDocument C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, graphics, printdocument

Iam new in WPF application development. I want to print the contents of a form to printer. I have following code

```
string s = "Name : Test" + Environment.NewLine +
                    "Age : 25" + Environment.NewLine +
                    "Sex : Male" + Environment.NewLine;

PrintDocument p = new PrintDocument();
p.PrintPage += delegate (object sender1, PrintPageEventArgs e1)
                {
                    e1.Graphics.DrawString(s, new Font("Times New Roman", 12), new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black), new RectangleF(0, 0, p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Width, p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Height));
};
try
{
  p.Print();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   throw new Exception("Exception Occured While Printing", ex);
}
```

I have used a pdf printer for printing document. I got pdf like this
[image]

I need to add a border to this print. is it possible to design printing output using this way?

Comment: You would have to manually draw the border yourself. You can get the page bounds from `PrintPageEventArgs`.

Comment: using graphics. draw lines. right? is any example code available?

Comment: Or DrawRectangle :) I'm not sure about example code, I'm afraid, but any GDI example with `Graphics` should work. You just need to use the page bounds from the event args.

Comment: e1.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 10, 10, 800, 500); this will show a border. But below code is not working.  e1.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red,20,20, p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Width, p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Height);

Comment: what is page bounds?

Comment: The printable area of a page.